# Why can't I reinstall Ubuntu Studio 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, grubrescue

I'm working with Ubuntu Studio 16.04. After an update this week, Grub2 does not work. I tried reinstalling Ubuntu Studio and formatting the SSD. The operating system was installed well, but when it tries to restart it returns the same fault of grub:

```
error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.  
Grub rescue>
```

I already lost all my work and I just want to reinstall Ubuntu, but not even formatting the hard disk and reinstalling the system is able to overcome this grub error.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problom with the ISO you burned on the install media.

Try redownlading and reburning the iso.